# How can I remove an element from local storage in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

i have sidebar with collapsible menu and i have to  remove the auto-collapsible option  when the  is page reload image is given below ,for this i have used the local storage for storing the parent node id but when i click the same parent node  then id from local storage should be removed but it don't
so please help me out!

javascript code is here:-

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#sidebarmenu').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
                let active = $('#sidebarmenu .show')
                let arr = []
                for (let i = 0; i < active.length; i++) {
                    let data = $(active[i]).attr('id')
                    arr.push('#' + data)
                }
                localStorage.setItem('activeCollapseGroup', JSON.stringify(arr))
            })
            let last = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('activeCollapseGroup'))
            console.log("this  data is inserted into " + last)

            if (last !== null) {
                $('#sidebarmenu .collapse').removeClass('show')
                for (let i = 0; i < last.length; i++) {
                    // console.log($('#sidebarmenu a[href="' + last[i] + '"]'))
                    $('#sidebarmenu a[href="' + last[i] + '"]').on('click', function (key) {
                        let clickedNode = $('#sidebarmenu a[href="' + last[i] + '"]')[0]
                        let data = JSON.stringify(clickedNode.getAttribute('href'))
                        last = last.filter((item) => item === data)
                        localStorage.setItem('activeCollapseGroup', JSON.stringify(last))
                    })
                }
                for (let i = 0; i < last.length; i++) {
                    $(last[i]).addClass('show')
                    $('#sidebarmenu a[href="' + last[i] + '"]').attr('aria-expanded', true)
                }
            }
        })


    </script>
```

image is given below:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRLHJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4EdH.png)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: localStorage.removeItem("mytime");

Answer (score 0):

localStorage.removeItem('stuff');

Comment: its not like that i have to remove the value  only selected value so localStorage.removeItem('stuff'); dosen't work for me !! please look at my code and help me out

Comment: Well, let's think about your steps:
1. assign button click that creates the entry into localstorage
2. render - check for existing local storage, then if it's found, show that element. |

If you're goal is to collapse "open" things, you need to modify the code of your button click function like so: 

1. check for localStorage var
2. if it's found, close it / remove it
3. if it's not found, save new one (like you currently are) | Does that make sense?

Comment: Christopher Smith  i got your answer but i have to remove the only the one element in value of local storage so other remains as same